# How to get access token from Dropbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am trying to list the files and folders that are in the Dropbox by using JavaScript. Can anyone suggest me how to get access token programmatically.
I can generate access token manually but I need to get from code.

Comment: Assuming you are using php. http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/      You need to use the php api section. Get the data you want. Then in the javascript make an ajax request for the data from your php file.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically get an access token for a user, your app needs to send them through the OAuth app authorization flow. When directly using JavaScript, ideally you'd use an SDK or library, e.g.,:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js

(Note that the Datastore API functionality is deprecated, but the rest isn't.)

The tutorial will guide you through linking an account:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/js

There's also more documentation and resources here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js

There's also an OAuth guide here that should serve as a good reference about the OAuth flow:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide

Otherwise, if you want or need to implement this manually, the following blog posts may be helpful:

for OAuth 1: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/
for OAuth 2: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/